# inet_pton() function gives only ip or ip and port number?

Tags: c, network-programming

In C does the function inet_pton() convert only the ip address from printble to string format or it also converts ip address and port number too? I mean, if I have a string of format A.B.C.D:E where A.B.C.D is the ip and E is the port  number, would I be able to use inet_pton for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not handle port numbers. The [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) specifies exactly what it expects for IPv4 addresses:

> `src` points to a character string containing an IPv4 network address in
>     dotted-decimal format, "ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd", where ddd is a decimal number
>     of up to three digits in the range 0 to 255.  The address is converted
>     to a `struct in_addr` and copied to `dst`, which must be `sizeof(struct
>     in_addr)` (4) bytes (32 bits) long.

Answer (score 3):

You have to split off the port number yourself. This is rather problematic since the way you go about doing that depends on whether the address is ipv4 or ipv6. I believe this issue is the reason many unix utilities use a `-p` option instead of the `:port` syntax to specify port.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getaddrinfo()` the swiss knife of the address conversion.

Comment: This is good advice but you still have to split off the port number yourself.