# How to Convert Between IP(v4/v6) Address (and Port) and String?

Tags: c, linux, string, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to port some Windows code that uses `RtlIpv4StringToAddressExA`/`RtlIpv6StringToAddressExA` and `RtlIpv6AddressToStringExA`/`RtlIpv4AddressToStringExA` to Linux and can't seem to find quite equivalent APIs. There seem to be plenty of ways to convert just the IP address to string (and back), but I can't find something that supports the port as well.

For instance, to convert `[2001:4898:d8:34:b912:426d:1c88:5859]:443` to an IP address from a string (and back).

To reiterate, I explicitly need an API that takes **port** into consideration.

Comment: You have to split off the port number yourself.

Comment: I'm explicitly looking for an API that does that already. Windows has one already. I find it hard to believe no one else has this problem on other platforms.

Comment: There is none. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525435/10795151

Comment: If it is truly the case that no Linux APIs support the port syntax that's going to be a pain to port existing Windows code that already uses this functionality.

Comment: There is a windows api that does that?

Comment: Did you read the question? I explicitly listed them already.

Comment: It would probably be trivial to just write it yourself.

Comment: I have access the Windows source for those functions, and they are not trivial. They are hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Every time I've needed such a thing I've written my own code to split up ip address and port so they can be passed to `getaddrinfo()` like normal. It's only a few extra lines.

Comment: Converting the address and port to string is simple enough to write manually. Taking a generic string that may be v4 or v6 and may or may not have a port and converting it to a struct is definitely more complicated. But it seems like I may have no choice.

Comment: Converting a generic ip address that might be v4 or v6 to the appropriate `struct sockaddr_XXX` is also very simple. `getaddrinfo()` is your friend.

Comment: [inet_pton](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) I think first extract port yourself, then `inet_pton(AP_INET6`

Comment: Well, if someone wants to add an answer saying there is no solution for Linux, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do this. You have to split off the port number yourself.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525435/10795151), which mentions that most utilities use a `-p port` argument instead of `:port` to specify the port.

If you really want something like this, it would probably be trivial to just write it yourself.